# Update DictProxy from multiple processes does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Why my dict does not update? Isn't DictProxy's purpose to work with cases like this ?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager 

def func(logtree):
    logtree['x'] = 'x'


def main():
    manager = Manager()
    logtrees = manager.dict()
    logtrees['a'] = {}
    logtrees['b'] = {}
    logtrees['c'] = {}

    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    for key in logtrees.keys():
        pool.apply_async(func, args=(logtrees[key],))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(logtrees)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

actual output: `{'a': {}, 'b': {}, 'c': {}}`

desired output: `{'a': {'x': 'x'}, 'b': {'x': 'x'}, 'c': {'x': 'x'}}`

Comment: Can we see the imports please? I wasn't aware of utility of Manager()

Comment: from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the answer is correct. You overwrite the manager with a normal dictionary.

```
logtrees = {key: dict(logtrees[key]) for key in logtrees.keys()}
```

You can observe this by adding the following lines

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager


def func(logtree):
    logtree['x'] = 'x'


def main():
    manager = Manager()
    logtrees = manager.dict()
    logtrees['a'] = manager.dict()
    logtrees['b'] = manager.dict()
    logtrees['c'] = manager.dict()

    pool = Pool(2)
    for key in logtrees.keys():
        pool.apply_async(func, args=(logtrees[key],))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(logtrees.__class__)  # <-------------------------------------- here
    logtrees = {key: dict(logtrees[key]) for key in logtrees.keys()}
    print(logtrees)
    print(logtrees.__class__)  # <-------------------------------------- here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
<class 'multiprocessing.managers.DictProxy'>
{'a': {'x': 'x'}, 'b': {'x': 'x'}, 'c': {'x': 'x'}}
<class 'dict'>
```

I hope the knowledge helps

Comment: I've used a DictProxy just because I wanted to update it from multiple processes, then use it as a simple dict, because it can be serialized with json.dump . It's not a wrong answer, it solved my problem with updating a dict from different processes.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager


def func(logtree):
    logtree['x'] = 'x'


def main():
    manager = Manager()
    logtrees = manager.dict()
    logtrees['a'] = manager.dict()
    logtrees['b'] = manager.dict()
    logtrees['c'] = manager.dict()

    pool = Pool(2)
    for key in logtrees.keys():
        pool.apply_async(func, args=(logtrees[key],))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    logtrees = {key: dict(logtrees[key]) for key in logtrees.keys()}
    print(logtrees)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```